# Not able to find .netrc in my Home directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is .netrc file  by default provided in the linux home directory or do we have to create it manualy. I am not able to find it .in ~/home
Rgds
Rp

Comment: no, it does not exist by default, it needs to be created manually. make sure the file isn't readable by any other user, as passwords stored within are plaintext.

Comment: `~/home` is the wrong location. If it's present at all, it is at `~/.netrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not provided by default and you have to create it manually, because after all, it contains your own credentials. 
Just create it with your favorite editor, and it would work.